# How to mock a http request post in python unittest

Tags: python, python-requests, python-unittest

First time write unittest.
Production code:

```
def get_session_token(organization_id):
    endpoint = get_endpoint(organization_id)
    response = requests.post(
        endpoint + "/some/url/part",
        data=json.dumps({
            "Login": CONFIG[organization_id]["username"],
            "Password": CONFIG[organization_id]["password"],
        }),
        headers={"Accept": "application/json"}
    )

    if response.status_code != 201:
        log.error("filename.get_session_token(%r): couldn't auth: %r %r",
                  organization_id, response, response.text)
        raise ValueError()

    return response.json()

def member(organization_id):
    session_key = get_session_token(organization_id)
    (some other code...)
```

I need to test member. And I have test code:

```
@patch('requests.post')
def test_member(self, mock_post):
    mock_post().status_code = 201
    mock_response = mock_post("some/url", data=ANY,
                              headers={"Accept": "application/json"})
    mock_response.status_code = 201
    (some other code...)
```

Every time I run test, it always raises ValueError()(which is a 403 error)

How can I bypass that requests.post and just get a 201?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch). And, you should provide a mock return value for the `mock_post` using `return_value`  - The value returned when the mock is called.

E.g.

`member.py`:

```py
import requests
import json


def get_session_token(organization_id):
    endpoint = 'http://localhost:3000/api'
    response = requests.post(
        endpoint + "/some/url/part",
        data=json.dumps({
            "Login": 'python',
            "Password": '123456',
        }),
        headers={"Accept": "application/json"}
    )
    if response.status_code != 201:
        raise ValueError()

    return response.json()


def member(organization_id):
    session_key = get_session_token(organization_id)
    return session_key
```

`test_member.py`:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
import unittest
import json
from member import member


class TestMember(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('member.requests.post')
    def test_member_success(self, mock_post):
        mock_post.return_value.status_code = 201
        mock_post.return_value.json.return_value = 'mock response'

        actual = member(1)
        self.assertEqual(actual, 'mock response')
        mock_post.assert_called_once_with(
            'http://localhost:3000/api/some/url/part',
            data=json.dumps({
                "Login": 'python',
                "Password": '123456',
            }),
            headers={"Accept": "application/json"}
        )

    @patch('member.requests.post')
    def test_member_failure(self, mock_post):
        mock_post.return_value.status_code = 400
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, member, 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Test result:

```bash
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                        Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/70098351/member.py           11      2    82%   18, 23
src/stackoverflow/70098351/test_member.py      11      0   100%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                          22      2    91%
```

Comment: That's very detailed! Thank you!

Comment: Very good answer!! However I believe the second test function should be called `test_member_failure` instead of `test_member_failure`..  There are two `test_member_success` functions.

Comment: @Diana Yes, I just copy and paste the first test case code, forget to change the name:)